# Failure associating EIP: InvalidParameterCombination: You must specify an allocation id when mapping an address to a VPC instance

Tags: terraform, elastic-ip

Given this:

```
resource "aws_instance" "example" {
  ami           = "ami-2757f631"
  instance_type = "t2.micro"
}

resource "aws_eip" "ip" {
  instance = "${aws_instance.example.id}"
}
```

from https://www.terraform.io/intro/getting-started/dependencies.html

I get an error:

```
* aws_eip.ip: Failure associating EIP: InvalidParameterCombination: You must specify an allocation id when mapping an address to a VPC instance
```

Any idea why?

Comment: Have you tried adding `vpc = true` to the `aws_eip` resource?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The `aws_eip` resource in Terraform uses the value of the `vpc` configuration attribute (`true` or `false`) as a toggle to decide if the resources `ID` should be it's `allocation_id`, or it's `public_ip`. We then use that `ID` in the API call to associate the EIP with the Instance.

In EC2 Classic, the `AssociateAddress` call expects the `public_id` value. In a EC2-VPC, it expects the `allocation_id` value.

For `aws_eip` resources attaching to Instance resources in a VPC, you need to include `vpc = true` in the `aws_eip` configuration.